# 2 Spring boot applications deployed in same server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have 2 spring boot applications(maven projects), which contain "spring-boot-starter-actuator" dependency, for checking health of the each application. While deploying both the applications in tomcat server, I get below exception -

```
2016-05-02 22:30:44.627 ERROR 12734 --- [ost-startStop-3] o.s.b.a.e.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter      : Could not register MBean for endpoint [dumpEndpoint]

org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.DataEndpointMBean@67e7c413] with key 'dumpEndpoint'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=dumpEndpoint
at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:625) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter.registerEndpoint(EndpointMBeanExporter.java:182) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter.locateAndRegisterEndpoints(EndpointMBeanExporter.java:162) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter.doStart(EndpointMBeanExporter.java:153) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter.start(EndpointMBeanExporter.java:276) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173) [spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51) [spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346) [spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149) [spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112) [spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851) [spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) [spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:149) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:129) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:85) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5155) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1738) [catalina.jar:8.0.21]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.8.0]
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=dumpEndpoint
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437) ~[na:1.8.0]
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898) ~[na:1.8.0]
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966) ~[na:1.8.0]
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900) ~[na:1.8.0]
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0]
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522) ~[na:1.8.0]
at org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.doRegister(MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:195) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:678) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:621) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
... 32 common frames omitted
```

Can anyone help me resolving this exception? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please may you add more information, and formatting, in the question?

Comment: see answer below provided by @dunni and you could read the documentation here http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-custom-mbean-names

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following properties in application.properties to configure a JMX domain for each of your applications (e.g. use the application name as domain):

```
spring.jmx.default-domain=applicationname
```

This configures the domain for all JMX endpoints which are added by Spring.

```
endpoints.jmx.domain=applicationname
```

This configures the JMX domain only for the actuator endpoints.

This will then prevent clashes of JMX beans with same names in different applications, because the domain will be added to the JMX name.